# Using secure print function in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, c11

I'm a **netbeans** user, I'm trying to change **printf** with the secure **printf_s** function but it didn't work. the editor is not able to figure it out ? the same for `scanf_s`.
I know it's a part of C11, everything is up to date. what's wrong ?

Comment: Can you paste a complete, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem as well as a more precise description of the symptom?

Comment: Thank you it's already solved! :D

Comment: Solved how? Please share the solution (by posting it as an answer) so others can benefit.

Answer (score 1):

While those functions are optional features of the C11 standard, in operational terms right now (October 2014) those functions are available only on the Microsoft compiler. If you're not using the MSFT compiler it won't work.

Comment: Thank you, all i can do now for security is range checking with condition statments :'(

Comment: Actually both `printf_s` and `scanf_s` are listed in C11, as **optional** features from Annex K (Bounds-checking interfaces).